# SSL certificate graded as C in Qualys

Tags: tls

Can you help in summarizing what would be the main threats for a web app when its SSL certificate is graded as **C** from the Qualys web scanning tool at https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/.

The summary of key findings from Qualys tool

```
This server supports weak Diffie-Hellman (DH) key exchange parameters. Grade capped to B. 
The server supports only older protocols, but not the current best TLS 1.2. Grade capped to C.
This server does not support Authenticated encryption (AEAD) cipher suites. Grade capped to B.
This server supports TLS 1.0. Grade will be capped to B from March 2020.
```

From their detailed listing

```
It currently supports only TLS 1.0. 
It does NOT support SSL 2, SSL 3, TLS 1.1, 1.2 and 1.3

# TLS 1.0 (suites in server-preferred order)
TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA (0xc014)   ECDH secp256r1 (eq. 3072 bits RSA)   FS   WEAK    256
TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA (0xc013)   ECDH secp256r1 (eq. 3072 bits RSA)   FS   WEAK    128
TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA (0x35)   WEAK  256
TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA (0x2f)   WEAK  128
TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA (0x39)   DH 1024 bits   FS   WEAK  256
TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA (0x33)   DH 1024 bits   FS   WEAK  128

Forward Secrecy Weak key exchange   WEAK

Uses common DH primes   Yes   Replace with custom DH parameters if possible (more info)
DH public server param (Ys) reuse   Yes
ECDH public server param reuse  Yes
```

I understand that upgrading the TLS certificate to support TLS 1.2 and 1.3;  remove support for lower versions, would decrease most of risks.

Same with applying stronger cipher suites and arranging the adequate ordering of them.

What I need to know if under the current situation, what types of attacks could this resource (Windows Server 2016) be exposed to ?

Thanks

Comment: You can search every keyword given, like "weak Diffie-Hellman (DH) key exchange parameters" on this site or via google and will find an attack.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, you need some clarification on few concepts:

- The reported problems aren't about the certificate, but the **protocols** your server is configured to support.
- TLS protects the **connection** between the server and the client. The weaknesses in the older versions of the protocol doesn't expose the server software to any vulnerabilities (although it may have other vulnerabilities on its own), but may expose the data transferred between the client and the server now or in the future, if recorded traffic can be decrypted later.

The Qualys SSL Server Test explains the vulnerabilities / weaknesses quite clearly:

- The reasons for the grade penalties are explained, if you click the `MORE INFO >>` link on the line.
- The Protocol Details section also has links for `(more info)`.

If you wish to get grade A by enabling TLS 1.2 and Perfect Forward Secrecy & disabling older protocols and weak ciphersuites, there are several tutorials you could follow. Alexander Hass is even maintaining a PowerShell script that can do this for you:

[Setup Microsoft Windows or IIS for SSL Perfect Forward Secrecy and TLS 1.2](https://www.hass.de/content/setup-microsoft-windows-or-iis-ssl-perfect-forward-secrecy-and-tls-12)